# Automorphisms of Affine plane

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I am working on the automorphisms of the affine plane and projective plane.

Can we extend an automorphism of an affine to projective plane?

As we know that we extend affine plane to projective plane. (by adding a  line at infinity)
Is there  a possibility to extend the collineations (automorphisms) from affine plane to projective plane.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Automorphisms of the projective plane are necessarily linear, whereas the affine plane has automorphisms that are non-linear, e.g. $(x,y) \mapsto (x, y + x^2).$

Comment: How about the affine plane at a point p, and derived projective plane at point p? That means can we extend automorphism of afiine plane at a point p to an automorphism of derived projective plane at a point p?

Comment: Dear Ryan, I'm not sure what you mean by the "derived projective plane at a point $p$".  Sorry!  Cheers,

Comment: Derived plane at a point p is, it consists of all points different from p and lines passing through p but punctured at p.

Comment: @Ryan: Dear Ryan, The problem is that a non-linear automorphism that fixes $p$ won't preserve lines through $p$ (it will take them to higher degree curves passing through $p$), and so won't act on the derived plane.  Regards,

Comment: An automorphism, called homothety in an affine plane can be extended to an automorphism, homology in  a derived projective plane.